# Floodlight randomly, dimly lights even when lightswitch is off

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting, dimmer-switch

This problem baffles me completely.  In one of our bedrooms, we have two floodlights connected to a one-way Z-wave dimmer switch.  Both floodlights are Cree BR30s.  When the light switch is off, one of the two floodlights randomly lights up very dimly.  If I remove the "problematic" light, the other floodlight does not randomly light up and continues to operate normally.  This leads me to believe that it can't be a problem with the light switch.  I plan to install an incandescent light today to see what happens when the light types are mixed.

I don't know what else to ask, except, how is this even possible?  When the floodlights were occupied by normal incandescent lights, this never happened.  What sort of debugging strategy would you all recommend?  Thank you!

UPDATE 1/28/2017: I *finally* ordered and installed the recommended dimmer switches and they work!

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006LQFHN2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LQFHN2)

Comment: What is the model number of your Z-wave dimmer? Some Z-wave dimmers are not LED compatible, even if the LED bulb is dimmable. If the Z-wave is indeed LED compatible, try using a different LED bulb (possibly even a different brand/model).

Comment: @mjohns615 I purchased the "GE Z-Wave Dimmer Switch 45606" from Amazon.  I guess it's two-way, not one-way.

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but if you don't want to replace the switch, if you replace one of the 2 floods with an incandescent this should stop happening.

Comment: Both led and cfl lights can intermittently flash or dimly light when they are controlled by devices that let even the slightest current pass through them when off. Like a switch with that little "find me at night" light or a dimmer. Using one normal bulb should stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the 45606 manual that this model is not designed for use with anything but incandescent loads:

> This dimmer switch is designed for use only with permanently installed
>   incandescent lighting
>   fixtures. Do not use it to control fluorescent lighting, transformer
>   supplied lighting/appliances, motorized appliances or receptacles. The
>   incandescent lighting controlled by this dimmer switch must not exceed
>   a total of 500 watts.

And

> Minimum Load: 40W, incandescent lamps only.
>   Maximum Load: 500W, incandescent lamps only.

From my understanding of these Z-Wave dimmers, the ones that are LED compatible utilize a neutral (white) wire. This model does not appear to have a neutral wire.

---

**Dimmable LED Compatible Model**

The `GE 12724 (ZW3005) Z-Wave, In-Wall Smart Dimmer (Interchangeable Paddles)` is listed as compatible with dimmable CFL and LED loads:

> UL Listed to work with dimmable LED & CFLs
>
> Screw Terminal installation; requires wiring connections for Line (Hot), Load,
>   **Neutral** and Ground. Traveler wire required for multi pole installation
>
> Maximum Load: 600W, incandescent; 150W Dimmable CFL/LED

Comment: I haven't found any LED-compatible dimmers, yet.  I found some part numbers that people say are working, but then the user manual says "only use with incandescent lighting", so I suppose they are no better.  For now, I will just pair one LED with one incandescent.  Is this in any way a fire hazard?  My guess is no.  My long term solution will be to replace the dimmers with on/off Zwave switches instead.

Comment: @dave even the on/off zwave switches may cause this behavior if they do not use a neureal wire to power their internal electronics.

Comment: @Dave, there should be no fire hazard with what you have proposed; however, there are dimmer models that will meet your needs. I have edited my answer to include a Z-Wave model that is dimmable CFL/LED compatible.

Comment: @mjohns Thanks again, ordered the right switches and installed them today.  They work perfectly!  Now I have to replace all of the other ones...  :(